# is it possible to return string after comparison in NumPy?

Tags: python, arrays, string, numpy, compare

I have written a code that going to compare the string in array using CSV. 
Here is the sample dataset

```
Doc   Cited_Doc
A     B | F | G
B     V | T
C     A | O | U | P | M
```

and here is my code

```
Input = np.loadtxt('C1_100.csv', delimiter=',' , dtype='unicode')

NumOfDoc = len(Input[:,1])
NumOfCol = len(Input[1,:])

for i in range(1, NumOfDoc):
    Cited = Input[:,1]
    Citing = Input[:,0]

bb=1 

for i in range(1, NumOfDoc):
    for j in range(1, NumOfDoc):
        #aa = np.core.defchararray.equal(Citing, Cited)
        aa =  np.isin(Citing, Cited)
        CitingCited = []
        if np.all(aa!=0):
            if bb==1:
                #CitingCited = [Citing[j],Citing[i]]
                a = np.core.defchararray.add(Citing[j], Citing[i])
                CitingCited.append(a)
            if bb>1:
                #CitingCited[bb,1]= Citing[j]
                #CitingCited[bb,1]= Citing[j]
                CitingCited.append(Citing[j])
                CitingCited.append(Citing[j])

        bb=bb+1

print('CitingCited')
```

After the comparison and I have tried to print aa, the result is returned

```
array([True,True,False])
```

and when I print CitingCited, the result is returned

```
[]
```

but I expect to see the result when I print CitingCited (the result that return True)

```
a = np.core.defchararray.add(Citing[j], Citing[i])
                    CitingCited.append(a)
```

like this

```
Doc Cited_Doc
A     C
B     A
```

any suggestions?

Comment: Variable and function names should follow the `lower_case_with_underscores` style. Why use for this NumPy? Also, to quote the docs, _The chararray class exists for backwards compatibility with Numarray, it is not recommended for new development. Starting from numpy 1.4, if one needs arrays of strings, it is recommended to use arrays of dtype object, string or unicode, and use the free functions in the numpy.char module for fast vectorized string operations._

Comment: I'm using the numpy because i heard that it's working faster than pandas.

Comment: Where did you hear that? Performance is a complex topic, and I don't think NumPy and Pandas are even competitors in the first place. Can you share what your data looks like?

Comment: i heard that from my friend. and my data is looking like as i have written. it has 2 columns, one is the main document and the second column is the list of cited document

Comment: _and my data is looking like as i have written. it has 2 columns, one is the main document and the second column is the list of cited document_ I just wanted to check the format, they're alphanumerical strings?

Comment: ahh, sorry for the misunderstand your meaning, yes, it is!

Comment: Then you should have a much easier time with Pandas.

Comment: I see, thank you for your suggestion, I will change to using pandas

Comment: Could you show part of the `Input` array?  I'm guessing it is (n,2) shape with some `Um` dtype.

Comment: Pandas uses python strings with object `dtype`.  `numpy` uses its own string dtype.  To use string methods you have to use `np.char` functions or `cararray`.  String handling isn't a strong point for numpy.

Comment: @AMC, he isn't using `chararray`.  `np.core.defchararray` is just another way of accessing the `np.char` functions.

Answer (score 0):

Let's see if I can recreate your data:

```
In [1]: txt ="""A,B|F|G 
   ...: B,V|T 
   ...: C,A|O|U|P|M 
   ...: """                                                                                               
In [2]: data = np.loadtxt(txt.splitlines(),delimiter=',',dtype='unicode')                                 
In [3]: data                                                                                              
Out[3]: 
array([['A', 'B|F|G'],
       ['B', 'V|T'],
       ['C', 'A|O|U|P|M']], dtype='<U9')
In [4]: n,m = data.shape                                                                                  
In [5]: n,m                                                                                               
Out[5]: (3, 2)
```

Then you loop:

```
In [6]: for i in range(1,n): 
   ...:     cited=data[:,1] 
   ...:     citing=data[:,0] 
   ...:                                                                                                   
In [7]: cited                                                                                             
Out[7]: array(['B|F|G', 'V|T', 'A|O|U|P|M'], dtype='<U9')
In [8]: citing                                                                                            
Out[8]: array(['A', 'B', 'C'], dtype='<U9')
```

You don't use the `i` in the loop.  Why loop at all?  I was going to ask why the 1 start in the loop, but realized that my sample doesn't have header line, which you are skipping.

In any case, what you now have is two 1d arrays of string dtype.

In the next step you again loop, twice, but again, the whole columns, not the `i'th` or `j'th` elements.

```
In [12]: np.isin(citing, cited)                                                                           
Out[12]: array([False, False, False])
```

What's the `isin` supposed to be detecting?  It compares the elements of two arrays.  None of the elements of `citing` appear in `cited` (yes, 'B' is a substring in 'B|F|G', but that's not what `isin` is testing for.

We could test `cited` against elements of `citing` if we split them on '|'.

```
In [18]: np.isin(['A','B','C'], ['B','F','G'])                                                            
Out[18]: array([False,  True, False])
In [20]: np.isin(['A','B','C'], ['V','T'])                                                                
Out[20]: array([False, False, False])
In [21]: np.isin(['A','B','C'], ['A','O','U'])                                                            
Out[21]: array([ True, False, False])
```

We could use ordinary string operations to test which `citing` strings are found in `cited` strings:

```
In [27]: [s for s in citing if s in cited[0]]                                                             
Out[27]: ['B']
In [28]: [s for s in citing if s in cited[1]]                                                             
Out[28]: []
In [29]: [s for s in citing if s in cited[2]]                                                             
Out[29]: ['A']
```

I could go on, but it's clear at this point, that this isn't really much of a `numpy` problem.  Think instead of two lists strings.

In fact to make it more explicit:

```
In [30]: Alist= citing.tolist(); Blist=cited.tolist()                                                     
In [31]: Alist, Blist                                                                                     
Out[31]: (['A', 'B', 'C'], ['B|F|G', 'V|T', 'A|O|U|P|M'])
```

And that `Blist` could be further split into a list of lists:

```
In [32]: [s.split('|') for s in Blist]                                                                    
Out[32]: [['B', 'F', 'G'], ['V', 'T'], ['A', 'O', 'U', 'P', 'M']]
```

As I wrote in a comment, `pandas` uses object dtype for strings, and strings are ordinary Python strings.  `numpy` instead uses `<U9` string dtypes.  I don't know enough of `pandas` to say whether it has added string utilites, but I suspect ordinary Python string utilities are enough.

`np.char` has functions that apply string methods to elements of an array.  They can be convenient, but they don't offer any speed improvements.

The `Out[32]` split can also be done:

```
In [34]: np.char.split(cited, '|')                                                                        
Out[34]: 
array([list(['B', 'F', 'G']), list(['V', 'T']),
       list(['A', 'O', 'U', 'P', 'M'])], dtype=object)
```

The `core.defchararray` is just another way of accessing these functions:

```
In [40]: np.core.defchararray.add                                                                         
Out[40]: <function numpy.char.add(x1, x2)>
```

Your use of `Cited` and `Citing` for the two column names is confusing.  Yes they mean different things, but I had to keep referring back to the definitions to keep track of which variable which was which.  One is a list of `docs` the other a list of citations.

My advise - skip the whole `pandas` and `numpy` usage for now, and focus on getting the string matches correct.  This is a Python list of strings problem.  Make sure your iterations make sense, at each step!